# How to query posts with featured images

Tags: post-thumbnails, meta-query

I basically want to use WP_Query to select 3 latest posts which have featured images and this is the only way I can think of.

regards

**edit**

tried

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( "post_type" => 'case-study', 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id', "posts_per_page" => '10', 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ) );
```

which doesn't work

I'm trying to add a custom field to add a hidden custom field to a post when there is a featured image attached (either true or false).

I've tried hooking into updated_post_meta, update_post_meta, wp_insert_post but I cant seem to match the $meta_key to "_thumbnail_id".

**edit**

```
function get_latest_with_featured_image( $args = array() ) {
    $args = array_merge( array( "post_type" => 'post', "meta_key" => "_thumbnail_id", "posts_per_page" => '10', 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ), $args );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    return $query->posts;
}

$posts = get_latest_with_featured_image( array(  "post_type" => "case-studies",  "posts_per_page" => 10 ) );
```

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to indicate what you're *actually* trying to accomplish? If your ultimate objective is to retrieve the three latest posts with featured iamges, please write your question accordingly. Then, you can add the other details as one implementation method that you tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: I have asked this before which people have indicated cant be done without extending the core which I dont want to do, therefor have asked a new question which will help accomplish (hopefully) a previous one

Comment: I would recommend *not* using the generic variable name `$query` for your custom query. I would name it something descriptive. But **more importantly**: did you add post-thumbnail support to your `case-study` post-type? Do you have `case-study` posts that have featured images attached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've provided the answer to your own question, query for meta key `_thumbnail_id` to get posts with a featured image:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
);
$latest_with_thumbnails = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: tried it, don't work...

Comment: What *exactly* did you try? What happened unexpectedly, or didn't happened that you expected to happen?

Comment: nothing was returned

Comment: Right my fault, custom post type was incorrect. Well, that was simple, thank you!